# How to left justify numeric columns in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

I have some columns in a c# Xaml app which are showing as right justifed, we need them to be left justified.
I think it should be able to be done in the Xaml, but not sure how.

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Value"
                Header="End Value" />
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Change" />
<dxg:GridColumn EditSettings="{dxe:TextSettings DisplayFormat=N2}"
                FieldName="Percent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Display must be fixed within the cell styles, so you can add one like this:

```
<dxg:GridColumn x:Name="colText" FieldName="Text" CellStyle="{StaticResource styleAligned}"/>
```

And then define the style in the resources like this:

```
<dxg:GridControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="styleAligned" TargetType="dxg:CellContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="XXX"/>
    </Style>
</dxg:GridControl.Resources>
```

There you can change XXX for Right, Left, Center, Justify....